# Missing icons of whole Adobe products

Tags: adobe-illustrator, adobe-photoshop, file-format, optimization, file-placing

This problem is quite unusual cause doesnt concern graphic design problems. I've recently migrated my Adobe softs from C disk to D and all icons of each product just missed and become default [image]

[image]

It'd be great if someone knows the solution!

Comment: Hi. Welcome to GDSE.  Tech support questions are generally off-topic here on GDSE. Sorry about that. You might be better to contact Adobe directly for tech support.  Since you are new here, please check out [our help pages on what topics you can ask about](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic). Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I once encounter the same exact problem. My app icons on the start menu just didn't appear. I tried a couple, there are people who come to different solutions.

There is [this post](https://superuser.com/questions/955586/blank-start-menu-icons-on-windows-10) in SuperUser forums on this issue that addresses the icon cache refreshing approach.

Although, the right solution for me is the scaling approach which mentioned in [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/1342092/1147167), another post of SuperUser forums.

If I will state more precisely:

> Good day! Fortunately, I fixed mine changing the icon scale (Mine was
>   at recommended 100% so whatever yours are I hope will apply to what I
>   did too) from 100% to 125%. It didn't fix it so I just changed it back
>   to 100%, and by my surprise, it was fixed!

Answer (score 0):

Right-click and take a look at the properties of these shortcuts. If you moved the files yourself, the odds are that the icon is still set to the old location, and that you can just quickly change it. Alternately, they will reappear on a reinstall.